# PDF Text Field Won't Show As Empty

Tags: forms, pdf

I have a surcharge text box that I want to perform calculations based on a subtotal field. There is a minimum 4.50 which is calculated when the subtotal is <112.5. When the subtotal is >=112.5 the calculation is subtotal *0.04. My problem is that I don't know how to program the field to show as empty when the subtotal is 0. 
Here is my code.

```
{
  var nSubtotal = this.getField("Subtotal").value;
  if(nSubtotal = "0")event.value = "";
  if( nSubtotal >= 112.5) event.value = nSubtotal * 0.04;
  if( nSubtotal < 112.5) event.value = 4.50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified (and be made to work) with something like this:

```
if (this.getField("Subtotal").value > 0) {
event.value = util.printf("%.2f", Math.min(560, Math.max(4.50, this.getField("Subtotal").value * 0.04))) ;
} else {
event.value = "" ;
}
```

Note that in this case, the formatting of the result field is done in the calculation, and therefore, the result field does NOT need any format set; this also prevents the result field to show a value based on incomplete calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I try to use this I get a Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list 2: at line 3. I forgot to mention that there is a maximum surcharge of $560.00 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; there is actually a closing parenthese missing in the second line; the code is now corrected, and the maximum surcharge logic built in… (hehe… people say I love one-liners…)

Comment: @ MaxWyss. Thank you. You were a big help.